# How to implement a Dropbox-like functionality for authenticated users to upload files?

Tags: 7, users

I want to give my users some sort of upload functionality - kind of like a Dropbox. The Dropbox client module seems to have many bugs and the patches aren't fixing them for me.

So basically I am looking for users to be able to JUST upload files.

I don't want them to be able to view files which have been uploaded by others.

Any suggestions about a suitable solution?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [filedepot](https://www.drupal.org/project/filedepot) module.

> The filedepot module is full featured Document Management module that
>   has a google docs like feel. It fulfills the need for an integrated
>   file management module supporting role and user based security.
>   Documents can be saved outside the Drupal public directory to protect
>   documents for safe access and distribution.

[image]

It works great as a ftp-like solution which allows users to upload files, except that it has a UI and is accessible the same way as default drupal pages. Lots of configuration available so you can limit the actions of users. You can also integrate [organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) with filedepot and create groups and folders available only to certain groups, if you want to get into private files for users.

or create a webform for authenticated users only and give them a file upload widget. Then you can browse the submissions in a tabular format. This allows users to upload files but not browse them if you set the permissions up properly. They will still be able to see their upload of course.

Comment: I actually don't recommend using this module because of the extremely poor performance once the filedepot has gigs of files/folders. Up to 6min wait times for one folder to open, and once you click another folder, thats another 6min. 

We hacked the module and removed the function that created the collapse/expand folder and improved load up by over 1000%.  It's not necessary especially if its fired on every folder click. 6min loads down to half second loads is massive. Also filedepot files module needs to be hacked to import files faster. PM me if someone needs help optimizing their filedepot

Answer (score 4):

All you need is the [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity) module.  It provides a permission called "add and upload new files" that will do just what you want.

Answer (score 1):

## Modules with a stable D7 release

#### Scald (D6 beta and D7)

Here is a quote about the [Scald: Media Management made easy](https://www.drupal.org/project/scald) module (from its project page):

> ... a popular and flexible way to handle media in Drupal.
>
> Scald can handle images, video, audio, tweets and even Flash files. Scald works with YouTube, Vimeo, Soundcloud and other many other providers. You can see a full list on the scald provider's page, you can also read our FAQ.
>
> For end-users Scald is a great option because you can use Scald with popular editing tools such as CKEditor, and with Plupload for multiple file uploads. Scald also has a very user-friendly media library, based on Views.
>
> For developers, one of the best things about Scald is that it treats all files as full-blown fieldable entities.
>
> Finally, Scald has been proven to scale. Some Scald sites have nearly a million media items. Users include Radio France (national public radio), ARTE (the Franco-German TV network), Le Figaro (the biggest newspaper in France). Scald is optimized for performance and uses its own caching system that works well with other caching layer (core filter cache etc.)

#### Take Control (D6 and D7)

Here is a quote about the [Take Control](https://www.drupal.org/project/take_control) module (from its project page):

> ... is a set of set of modules for Drupal for managing various administrative tasks particularly related to the file system. Beginning with version 2.0, the module has been refactored into a core/add-on architecture, where a core module take_control provides common routines and settings, whereas the bulk of front-end user interaction comes from add-on modules (e.g. file browser etc).
>
> Currently, there are 2 add-on modules:
>
> 1. **File Browser**: A complete File Browser/File Manager for Drupal. Allows you to manage your Drupal file-system directly through Drupal without needing FTP or your Hosting Control Panel access.
> 2. **Quick Permissions**: Many Drupal administrators are troubled by the: Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006
>    directive in Drupal file-system root's .htaccess file that effectively prevents write access to the file-system folder outside Drupal.
>    This module allows you to take control of the file-system folder by specifying custom permissions on it from Drupal. Additionally, you can specify custom permission / delete any directory/file owned by Drupal using this module.

#### Filedepot (D6 and D7)

Here is a quote about the [Filedepot](https://www.drupal.org/project/filedepot) module (from its project page):

> ... is full featured Document Management module that has a google docs like feel. It fulfills the need for an integrated file management module supporting role and user based security. Documents can be saved outside the Drupal public directory to protect documents for safe access and distribution.
>
> Checkout the [filedepot_linkit](http://drupal.org/project/filedepot_linkit) module which supports browsing and inserting filedepot links from WYSIWYG editors.

#### Document (D6 and D7)

The [Document](https://www.drupal.org/project/document) module is a *Document Management System* for Drupal. Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> Features:
>
> - Complete integration with Drupal node system. This module adds a custom Node Type, Document. Each Document you create is a Drupal node, and hence enjoys all features available to a node.
> - Support for Document revisions/versioning - This module allows you to maintain multiple versions/revisions of the same document.
> - Views 2 Integration - The custom fields added by the module to the Document node type are accessible in Views, plus the module provides some useful out-of-the box Views.
> - Theming support
> - Searching - The documents being nodes are fully indexable by the Drupal search system. In addition, the module provides its own custom search for Documents.
> - A couple of blocks are available for document search that can be placed flexibly in your theme layout.

#### elFinder file manager (D7)

The [elFinder](https://www.drupal.org/project/elfinder) module integrates with [elFinder](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder), which is a open source AJAX file manager.  Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> Features:
>
> - Integrated with [WYSIWYG API](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) capable editors: CKEditor, FCKeditor, TinyMCE, BUEditor (D6), jWYSIWYG (D6), YUI, WYMeditor.
> - Multiple file upload.
> - File copying/moving with Drag & Drop support.
> - Quick file and directory rename.
> - Image resizing.
> - Lightbox-preview.
> - Context menu with generic file/directory operations.
> - Inline text file editing.
> - Favourites directory list.
> - Directory selection history.
> - Working with archives.
> - File descriptions.

#### CMIS API (D7)

The [CMIS API](https://www.drupal.org/project/cmis) module aims to provide a generic API for integrating with [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) compliant Enterprise CMS (ECM) systems.

## Modules with an unstable D7 release or for D6 only

There are a few more modules that might look like a possible fit, though they are, in general, perceived as rather buggy / unstaled, or only support old (D6) Drupal releases so far. Below are some more details about those modules.

#### Media (D7, but perceived unstable these days)

Here is a quote about the [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module (from its project page):

> The Media module provides an extensible framework for managing files and multimedia assets, regardless of whether they are hosted on your own site or a 3rd party site - it is commonly referred to as a 'file browser to the internet'.
>
> Media is a drop-in replacement for the Drupal core upload field with a unified User Interface where editors and administrators can upload, manage, and reuse files and multimedia assets. Any files uploaded before Media was enabled will automatically take advantage of the many of the features it comes with.

#### Media Browser Plus (D7, though only a beta version)

There is also the [Media Browser Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_browser_plus) module, which is an enhancement module for the [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module, with additions such as:

- Adding tags to media when uploading.
- Searching media.
- Hierarchical taxonomy based organization e.g. “folders".
- Mirroring folder taxonomy to filesystem"
- Drag & Drop to move files between folders.
- Multi selection of files.
- Bulk operations on files.
- Media Basked to download multiple files at once.

#### Asset (D7, though only a beta version)

Here is a quote about the [Asset](https://www.drupal.org/project/asset) module (from its project page):

> ... proposes a new approach to the media management in Drupal, resolving a long-standing problem of reusable media files (images, videos, documents, etc) that evolved into the problem of reusable media content (images/videos/documents/etc with the attached content like description/licence/etc).
>
> The Asset module provides new entity called Media Asset and the set of Media Assets examples (Image, Video, Audio, Document, Image Gallery, Free HTML), which can be enabled optionally.

#### Web File Manager (D6)

The '[Web File Manager](https://www.drupal.org/project/webfm)' module is for D6 only. And issue [WebFM for Drupal 7](https://www.drupal.org/node/604018) has status *Closed (Won't fix)*. But there is also an ongoing discussion about a [Ground-up rewrite of WebFM](https://www.drupal.org/node/592956).

Answer (score 0):

I created a new module that supports file uploads from various third-party services such as Dropbox, Google Drive, Box, OneDrive and Instagram:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/file_chooser_field

I am planning to add more plugins in the future. Also the built-in plugin API allows other developers created their own plugins. Check `Example.php` plugin and `file_chooser_field/modules/file_chooser_field_instagram/plugins/Instagram.php`

The module uploads only user files (using user's account), it is not using shared folders/files.

Comment: That really sounds interesting but I think that's not the answer OP is looking for. Or does your module bring some advanced privacy on uploaded files already? Maybe you could clarify that.